# Obtain real OpenGL texture format

Tags: opengl, cuda, nvidia

In my application I need to update a texture every frame and to do this very fast I am using CUDA, also because my initial data are 24bit BGR.

I created a texture this way:

```cpp
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, DimY, DimX, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

Then I use `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage`, `cudaGraphicsMapResources` and  `cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray` to do a `cudaMemcpy2DToArrayAsync`, but I see on my PC it does not work well because the texture is really a BGRX8, so I created a CUDA kernel to convert from 24bit BRG to 32 RGB. What I would like to do now, is make it generic checking the real format of the texture, but I haven't found a way.
There is a way to get the real format of a texture? or of the cuda array?

**EDIT** Try to add more information,
I create a texture this way:

```cpp
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, Dx,Dy, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

then map it to CUDA:

```cpp
CUDACK(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&registeredTex, texture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsNone));
CUDACK(cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &registeredTex, 0));
CUDACK(cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&mappedArray, registeredTex, 0, 0));
```

then to update the texture if I do:

```cpp
cudaMemcpy2DToArrayAsync(mappedArray, 0, 0, image_vec, Dx*3, Dx, Dy, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream);
```

the colors are incorrect:
[image: incorrect CMY]
instead of
[image: correct CMY]
so, to show it correctly I did a kernel that convert BGR to RGBA, and it works, on my pc, what I am asking, how can I make it in way that works on every pc? maybe there is a graphic card that handles BGR texture or 24 bit ones. can I obtain information about texture real storage?
I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

To get the effective target of a texture object (if the target is unknown)

```cpp
glGetTextureParameteriv(
    texture,
    GL_TEXTURE_TARGET,
    &target
);
```

to get the internal format of a specific level

```cpp
glGetTextureLevelParameteriv(
    texture,
    mipmaplevel, //e.g. 0
    GL_TEXTURE_INTERNAL_FORMAT
    &format
);
```

I deliberately used the named functions, which requires OpenGL version 4.5. But there are also `glGetTexParameteriv` and `glGetTexLevelParameteriv` (OpenGL 2+).

**Reference:**

- https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexParameter.xhtml
- https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexLevelParameter.xhtml